# How can I use a custom json scheme with a yaml?

Tags: json, yaml, visual-studio-code

I try to map a **custom json schema** to a **yaml** file, based on this example:

```
"json.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "/*.foo.json"
        ],
        "url": "./myschema.json"
    }
]
```

this is my setting:

```
"json.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [
            "/home/ubuntu/test.yaml"
        ],
        "url": "/home/ubuntu/test-schema.json"
    }
]
```

When I open the `test.yaml` file, I don't see that a JSON Schema is mapped  `No JSON Schema`.

I'm sure I miss something basic, but I can't figure out?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is something you can do (not straightforward). What you can actually do is specify in your YAML the schema you want to use, ie:

Assuming a "/home/ubuntu/myschema.json" and a "/home/ubuntu/test.yaml", your "/home/ubuntu/test.yaml" will look like this:

```
$schema: "/home/ubuntu/myschema.json"

name: Heodthre
humongous: dice
...
```

Late response, but may be helpful to someone.